# Can't Configure Android SDK in Eclipse in Ubuntu After Upgraded to 10.10

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, sdk

I have installed eclipse 5.2 in ubuntu 10.10. In the 'Install New Software', it show Android Developments Installed. And when i goto preferences window, Android is not listed in the left panel. Already i was running Android SDK in ubuntu 10.04, after i upgraded ubuntu OS, eclipse is not showing the Android.

Comment: Have you resinstalled the Google Eckipse Android SDK via the Ecliplse Update Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 3.5.2 probably?
If you have a good Internet connection just reinstall Eclipse and then add Android Plugin. It took me about 20 min. Just don't forget to delete .eclipse folder in your home directory (that's where all settings are). Deleting this folder alone and then starting Eclpise can probably help also.
Besides why don't you downlod Eclipse 3.6 from Eclipse website? It's zero configuration, just unzip it in you home directory and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse from 10.10 software channel is broken with ADT. Do not install eclipse from there.

Do not use Eclipse 3.6 too, its not certified to work with ADT.

Download 3.5.2 version from [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Older_Versions_Of_Eclipse)
Install ADT as pernormal, and you are all set.

However, I do find that the emulator in 10.10 runs horribly slow and CPU intensive, which is why I am switching to Windows for Android devs.